# PowerShell Convert "return" to HTML

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have a PowerShell script that runs `robocopy` on two drives for backup and then send an email with the job results. It runs every evening. When I originally wrote the script, my test backups were small enough that I could include the backup log in the body of the message, and also as an attachment. However, with the script actually doing my live backups, the log is way too long for that, well over 100MB, so I don't get notification on the job's status.

I am looking for a way to get just a summary of the job. I came across a script that will give me just what I want, but I don't know how to turn the scripts output into something I can email as an attachment, or include in the body of an email message.

The script I found is here: [Capturing Robocopy Metrics: Scanning the Log File](https://thescriptlad.com/2015/02/15/robocopy-metrics_part_one/). The output I want looks like this:

```
LogFilePath  : 150208TargetServer_S_MSO_R.TXT
Start        : Sun Feb 08 21:00:01 2015
End          : Sun Feb 08 21:05:53 2015
Source       : \\SourcerServer\S$\Group\MSO\
Destination  : \\TargetServer\R$\Platinum_Service_Replications\Group\MSO\
TotalDirs    : 3217
TotalFiles   : 30920
TotalMBytes  : 186,863.61
CopiedDirs   : 1
CopiedFiles  : 4
CopiedMBytes : 55.84
FailedDirs   : 0
FailedFiles  : 0
FailedMBytes : 0
SpeedMBMin   : 599.840
SOURCERSERVER:
TARGETSERVER:
```

The line of code "I think" I need to convert to HTML is

```
return $dataColl, $sourceServer, $sourceDrive, $targetServer, $targetDrive, $replicatingSysAdmin, $dataObject.LogFilePath
```

I've tried

```
$Results = $dataColl, $sourceServer, $sourceDrive, $targetServer,
           $targetDrive, $replicatingSysAdmin, $dataObject.LogFilePath
```

and

```
Get-Process |
    select ProcessName $dataColl, $sourceServer, $sourceDrive, $targetServer,
        $targetDrive, $replicatingSysAdmin, $dataObject.LogFilePath |
    ConvertTo-Html |
    Out-File results.html
```

and even this

```
Write-Host $dataColl, $sourceServer, $sourceDrive, $targetServer,
    $targetDrive, $replicatingSysAdmin, $dataObject.LogFilePath
```

But I can't get any output other than what "return" above gives me at the command line. Can anyone suggest a way to get the HTML, or body text I'm looking for? I'm not locked in to this script so if someone has a better method, that's ok, just as long as I can stitch into my existing `robocopy` script.

Also, if you need me to upload any samples, I can.

Answer (score 0):

i think, you have multiple types of Data here. You can create a custom object or add the remaining data to an existing Object and then convert to html.

Modify the scripts last line to below

```
$dataColl | AddMember -MemberType Property -Name sourceServer -Value $sourceServer
$dataColl | AddMember -MemberType Property -Name sourceDrive -Value $sourceDrive
$dataColl | AddMember -MemberType Property -Name targetServer -Value $targetServer
$dataColl | AddMember -MemberType Property -Name targetDrive -Value $targetDrive
$dataColl | AddMember -MemberType Property -Name LogFilePath -Value$dataObject.LogFilePath
```

then

```
return $dataColl
```

you can convert the script output to html like below.

```
.\script.ps1 | ConvertTo-html
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Prasoon. Changing the last line as to what you suggested did not work for me. What I ended up using was this: `$HTML = $dataColl | ConvertTo-HTML -head $head -precontent "<h4>DR Backup Results for STKBKX103 Drive E</h4>" | Out-String` along with some HTML formatting, and then using `$Body = $HTML` in send-mailmessage. It works, and it gives me readle output, but I would really like to get output that looks like the output in my original post. Thanks again, Rick